# ASP.NET Core Razor precompiled views in a class library

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, publish, precompile

Is this possible? Adding the following two lines to a csproj for a web application enables precompilation and produces a `Project.PrecompiledViews.dll`:

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0" />
```

Adding the same two lines to a class library which contains views does not produce a `Library.PrecompiledViews.dll`. Is this not currently supported, or does a class library require a little more coaxing?

Comment: The tool can only be run on projects targeting a run-able tfm (e.g net4x or netcoreapp1.x). https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/blob/rel/1.1.0/testapps/ClassLibraryWithPrecompiledViews/ClassLibraryWithPrecompiledViews.csproj shows some of the mechanics to run it as part of the build.

Comment: I am targeting `netcoreapp1.1`. Your link is for a csproj that isn't a class library though, unless I'm misunderstanding stuff? `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` requires an entry point. Do you need to fudge that side of things with an empty `Main()` to get the precompilation tools to kick in? If so is this something that is planned to be improved in the future?

Comment: Yeah, the plan to change it in the future. But for the time being, it has to be an executable project including a Program.Main. The Main can be marked internal so it doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks for the info Pranav,